# Find all positive integer $n$ that satisfy $ n^{2019} \equiv 7 \pmod{2019}$ where $1<n<2019$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all positive integer   $n$  that satisfy$ \  n^{2019}   \equiv 7 \pmod{2019}$ where $1<n<2019$

Honestly, I have no idea how to manage this problem. I just knew about Fermat's little theorem , but seems like it doesn't help me at all to solve this problem.

Maybe we try to solve $ \  n^{2019}   \equiv 1 \pmod{2019}$ and $n$ is a number multiple of $7$ ?

Thank you and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Note:  $2019=3\times673$

Comment: As $2019=3\cdot673$

$$n^{2019}\equiv7\pmod3\iff n\equiv1$$

$$n^{2019}\equiv7\pmod{673}\iff n^3\equiv7$$

Comment: $2029$ is prime so the solution to $n^{2029}\equiv7\mod 2029$ is $n\equiv7\mod 2029$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : So you mean to say that in 10 years this task is easier to solve?

Comment: @LutzL It's cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From CRT we have the system

$x^{2019}\equiv 7\bmod 3$

$x^{2019}\equiv 7\bmod 673$

The first equation reduces to $x=1\bmod 3$ via $x^{n+2}\equiv x^n\bmod 3$ for all $n\ge 1$ (Fermat).  So we have one residue $\bmod 3$.

Now for the fun part.  What becomes of the second equation?

Fermat's result gives $x^{2019}\equiv x^{1347}\equiv x^{675}\equiv x^3\bmod 673$.  So everything turns on whether $7$ is a cubic residue $\bmod 673$.  With $673$ being one greater than a multiple of $3$ there are either three roots or none.

If $7$ is a cubic residue $\bmod 673$ then $7^{224}\equiv 1$.  Test this with the squaring and multiplication method of exponentiation:

$7^2\equiv 49$

$7^3\equiv 343$

$7^6\equiv 547$

$7^7\equiv 464$

$7^{14}\equiv 609$

$7^{28}\equiv 58$

$7^{56}\equiv 672$

$7^{112}\equiv 1$

$\color{blue}{7^{224}\equiv 1}$

The test passes.  We then have $x\equiv 7^{1/3}\equiv (7^{225})^{1/3}\equiv 7^{75}\bmod 673$.  Using the squaring and multiplication method again gives $194$.

We have two more cube roots which must have the form

$-97(1\pm\sqrt{-3})\bmod 673$

in order for all three roots to sum to zero and give a product of $194^3\equiv 7$.  Let us render

$\sqrt {-3}\equiv\sqrt{-676}\equiv26\sqrt{-1}\equiv26\sqrt{5×673-1}\equiv26\sqrt{3364}\equiv26×58\equiv162$

(We could have also rendered $\sqrt{-1}\equiv 58$ from the cubic residue test above, as $58$ precedes $672$ in the squaring process.)

Then the remaining cube roots are

$-97(1\pm162)\equiv \{138,341\}\bmod 673$

And so we have our modulo $3$ and modulo $673$ components

$x\equiv 1\bmod 3$

$x\in\{138,194,341\}\bmod 673$

Finally:  take each residue from the $\bmod 673$ equation and add $673$ successively until we get a result satisfying the $\bmod 3$ equation.  Thereby

$\color{blue}{x\in\{811,1540,1687\}\bmod 2019}$

Answer (score 0):

Use software than allows for a complete enumeration.  For instance *Mathematica* code for this follows:

```
t = Table[{n, Mod[n^2019, 2019]}, {n, 2, 2018}];
Select[t, #[[2]] == 7 &][[All, 1]]
(* {811, 1540, 1687} *)
```

There appears to be 3 solutions for $1<n<2019$.

Comment: Did you check if Mathematica has a function for modular powers? As a CAS, it should have. This avoids computing with very large numbers and is thus much faster.

Comment: @LutzL Two lines of code and 0.08 seconds of computer time taken to answer the question as asked.  And you ask about something else being much faster?  Given the downvote and the close vote(s), it appears this forum has a low tolerance for a diversity of approaches to get the same answer.

Comment: These kind of questions are usually not about brute-forcing the solution, but about clever ways to reduce the problem into components that can, with more or less effort, also be solved manually. (Mine is neither down nor delete vote.)

Comment: @LutzL I do understand that and greatly admire folks who figure out extremely clever ways to solve a problem.  At the time of my answer, no one else had answered.  And I don't believe that knowing the answer before a clever approach is proposed is necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: It's a borderline thing, but that kind of information (CAS solution without any theoretical considerations) IMO is - on math.SE - better located in a comment to the question than as an answer.

Comment: @LutzL Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: Mine is neither down nor delete vote too.

Comment: How I would solve it with CAS:  Break up the problem into its $\bmod 3$ and $\bmod 673$ components.  From that decomposition $x$ is one greater than a multiple of $3$ and $x^3\equiv 7\bmod 673$.  Program to solve that system and you have only 673 trials with all numbers below $10^9$.

Comment: In **pari/gp**: `for(n=2,2018,if(Mod(n,2019)^2019==7,print1(n", ")))`. Output: `811, 1540, 1687,`.

Comment: With theory: `for(n=2,2018,if(gcd(n,2019)==1,m=Mod(n,2019);h=znorder(m);z=znlog(7,m,h);if(z&&2019%h==z,print1(n", "))))`.